# Disable offsite mail relaying

Tags: email, smtp, relay, disable, offsite

RHEL6  | High Sev

**Vulnerability Title**
SMTP unauthenticated 3rd-party mail relay

**Vuln Description**
lity is that other organizations, in an attempt to stop the flow of spam, may throw away any mail originating from your server (including legitimate mail from your users).

Answer (score 0):

Following FIX Helped, take backup of file

1. Comment out the below entry
   cd /etc/mail

[root@mail]# cat sendmail.mc | grep -v ^dnl | grep -i smart
define(`SMART_HOST',`relaymail.sapient.com')dnl
[root@mail]#
[root@mail]#

2. Below entry should be commented out 
   [root@ mail]# cat sendmail.mc | grep -v ^dnl | grep -i mailerta
   FEATURE(`mailertable',`hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl

[root@mail]# cp -p sendmail.mc sendmail.mc.bkp.`date +%F`
[root@mail]#

[root@mail]# m4 sendmail.mc > sendmail.cf

3. Add below entry in /etc/mail/mailertable to disable offsite mail relay

gmail.com       smtp:[192.168.100.x]
.               error:Mail to external domain is prohibited
[root@ mail]#

it helped to fix.
Hopefully will help, i searched a lot and finally this worked so thought to share.